# How to import Outlook contact using reactjs

Tags: reactjs, outlook-restapi

I want to fetch the all the contacts of user of outlook.

I am struggling for this particular things. I also done lot of RnD. But unable to get the any helpful resource for reactjs integration.I had came across below two site and I implemented both.But result is not as per expectation.

1.https://www.design19.org/blog/import-hotmail-contacts-windows-live-contact-api/
Here I am getting response but its empty array. If I replace `me/contacts/` to `me` then it give my details properly but for `me/contacts/` or for any other path its giving empty array.

2.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/javascript-tutorial

This is purely JS thing, I also tried to convert this in reactjs but most of the things are done using Jquery and JS and that is why its giving an issues like `callback() is not defined` and its like things.

Please help me for this.

Comment: [Lavlesh Mishra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5863869) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65422481) saying "Kindly follow this link: Register app. Create Token Get Profile https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/react?tutorial-step=1"